# Using authentication so users can only see their own data using mongodb and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I am using node.js to create a application so users can see only their own data when they login. For now i am using postman. User are authenticated using jwt tokens.jwt token does contain userid. I have added the user id in the .get url so only the id entered data will be displayed. but i want to create a get method so when the user logs and his and his jwt token is generated he can only see his or her own details without having to put the id in the url. Kindly help me with this because the next step is i have to integrate my nodejs to my angular

postman

[image]

router.get

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you should let your backend handle which data is passed out instead of hiding the data behind routes in the frontend.

Comment: I need to implement some logic on my get router so it can pick the user id from the token and only display the current user details

Comment: Do you use ```jsonwebtoken``` in your backend? How do you sign the tokens? You know that everybody can get the ```userid``` from the token, or?

Comment: The jwt token contains the user id and name.The jwt token is generated when the user logs in with valid userid and password. The jwt token is encrypted

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. You already saved the id in the token and sent it to the server. So you don't need the url parameter there, as you can get the users id from the token.

Comment: i need to implement a get router so when the user logs in he can only see his own data. in my current implementation the user has to manually add his id on the url as you can see from the picture. i need to create a get router so when user logs in he can olny see his own data without having to write his id on the url

Comment: @HamzaJunaid ask yourself this, if you already have the user ID in the jwt token, which the server can verify and decode, why do you need the ID in the route

Comment: I have some problems implementing a get method which can decode id from jwt token and display the data of only that particular id. As you can see i have added the id.url but i want a get method in which the user should not enter his id in the url but get his own data when he logs in